# Return all non leaf nodes using Recursive CTE in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table with data

```
id       name       mgtId
--------------------------
1        joe         null
2        jack         1
3        jill         1
4        paul         2
5        ron          4
6        sam          2
```

mgtId references id. How can I select non leaf nodes(joe, jack, paul) using CTE.

Comment: Why you want/need a recursive solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
from table
where id in (select mgtId from table)
```

Comment: It does not select the root node

Comment: This query will select joe, jack, and paul, just as you requested.

Comment: I will accept the answer but to get the root node, you have to use union with the same table where mgtId is null

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer... what row are you considering to be the root node?

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
;with parents_id as (
   select distinct mgtId as id
   from your_table
)
select *
from your_table t
inner join parants_id p on t.id = p.id
```

**UPDATED** 25 aprl 2012

I come to [test above query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/67716/return-all-non-leaf-nodes-using-cte-in-ms-sql) and it works and also return root node:

```
select * 
into #your_table
from (
select 1 as id, 'joe' as name, null as mgtId union all
select 2,        'jack   ',      1  union all
select 3,        'jill  ' ,      1 union all
select 4,        'paul '  ,      2 union all
select 5,        'ron '   ,      4 union all
select 6,        'sam'    ,      2  ) T


;with parents_id as (
   select distinct mgtId as id
   from #your_table
)
select *
from #your_table t
inner join parents_id p on t.id = p.id
```

results:

```
id name    mgtId id 
-- ------- ----- -- 
1  joe     null  1  
2  jack    1     2  
4  paul    2     4
```

Comment: It does not select the root node(joe).

Comment: Are you sure? I have check for both and root node is included into results, see updated comment.

Comment: Sorry, your solution does work. I framed a wrong example by the way, the table might contain some nodes which are not linked and those should also be selected

Answer (score 0):

with cte as(
select id,mgtId  from mgr_emp 
)
select b.id,b.name ,b.mgtId ,a.mgtId from cte a right join mgr_emp b 
on b.mgtId =a.id